# Update table after data in one column is updated(recalculated)

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm building a simple page with DataTable enabled table.

Data that comes from my server looks like so:

```
[{"name": "John","salary": 2000,"bonus1": 100,"bonus2": 100},
 {"name": "Jack","salary": 2500,"bonus1":   0,"bonus2": 200},
 {"name": "Bill","salary": 2000,"bonus1": 300,"bonus2": 300}
]
```

I need to add and calculate a fifth column that will represent percentage value of salaries for employees (salary/sum of all salaries)

In `fnPreDrawCallback` I am able to modify `oSettings.aoData` so when I do `console.log(oSettings.aoData)` I get correct values, but table has that column empty.

My `fnPreDrawCallback` function looks like this:

```
"fnPreDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
          iTotal = [0, 0, 0]; //declared in $(document).ready
          var dataLength=oSettings.aoData.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                iTotal[0] += oSettings.aoData[i]._aData.salary;
                iTotal[1] += oSettings.aoData[i]._aData.bonus1;
                iTotal[2] += oSettings.aoData[i]._aData.bonus2;
            }

          for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                oSettings.aoData[i]._aData.percent=(oSettings.aoData[i]._aData.salary / iTotal[0] * 100).toFixed(2)+'%';

            }
          console.log(oSettings.aoData);
        },
```

Here is my code: http://live.datatables.net/umezez/13/edit

My question: **Where I should update my data so that updates will be visible in table?**

I would like to avoid using selectors and updating content of DOM, because I would like to be able to export my table using TableTools or server-side processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why don't you simply do both things, update aoData ( so that you can export ) and update the html by yourself ( so that it displays correctly )

I know it's a hack, but it should work :)

http://live.datatables.net/umezez/16/edit

Edit using fnUpdate()

http://live.datatables.net/umezez/23/edit

Comment: I know about that hack from my previous question and Your answer :) Allan wrote me on datatables forum that I should use fnUpdate, but I can't figure out how to use it in my case, in which event I should update aoData to see my changes in table. I know that this is asking the same question over and over but in real report I'll have about 30 columns and 100+ rows. Your solution is the best for now, but if there would be an option to just modify aoData and see updates that would be awesome :)

Comment: @Misiu ok i'll look into a solution using fnUpdate

Comment: @Misiu i made it in time to grab the bounty i hope, here is the solution, you use fnUpdate() in the click handler http://live.datatables.net/umezez/23/edit

Comment: Hi again :) This is almost perfect :) because percent column is updated when I click show/hide button. But I think it won't be a problem to `fnUpdate` to second click handler. This way updates will be visible after I move rows. Hope this is clear enough :) Except that everything is just fine :)

Comment: I've made little modification: http://live.datatables.net/umezez/24/edit I know that this can be optimized, but for now this works greate. Thanks again, You save my day!

Comment: You read my mind :) I was thinking of a way to move Your code to function. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataTables footer callback check below link
http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

also check this discussion
http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/3605/addition-or-sum-of-column-values/p1

Comment: `fnFooterCallback` is fired after `fnPreDrawCallback`. You didn't understand my question. I know how to add summary, I need to update column. I can modify aoData, thats no problem, I need to know how to display it after update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

http://live.datatables.net/umezez/19

basically you need to calculate the total of salaries first (I moved your data to a variable and calculate the total before the table is rendered)
and after that you need to use fnRender function on the % column to calculate and display you percentage like this (below is a column definition for %)

```
 {
            "sTitle": "%",
            "bVisible": true,
            "sType": "string",
            "sWidth": "50px",
            "sClass": "center percent",
            "mData": "percent",
          "fnRender": function(o) {return o.aData.salary/totalSalaries}
        }
```

Comment: `fnRender` is deprecated. Second thing: moving calculation outside table helped at the beginning, but try to add rows from second table to first. The percent column isn't refreshing with Your modifications added. Thanks for giving this a try :)